# Is there a way to pause and resume the traffic goes to a target in AWS target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I recognize 1 instance in my AWS target group is actually not functioning well although its health check is ok, I want to pause the traffic to this instance, fix the problem and then return the traffic to this instance.

The only way I see is by deregistering the target and register it again.
I hoped to find some kind of pause and resume option.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Auto Scaling Group` theres tab called `Instance Management`.

You can check your instance there and from `Actions` menu pick `Set to Stand-by`.

It will deregister this instance from all assigned to ASG Target Groups, and if you put this instance to `In Service` state - it will assign it then automatically.

Comment: I currently don't use auto scaling, is it possible with auto scaling?

Comment: @AviMarcus, yes, it's for autoscaling, without ASG you can only manually deregister from target groups